# Curl with vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote, vcpkg

I am working on a windows 10 using wsl-2 using remote wsl 
i am trying to attach an external library using vcpkg 
one trail pacakge i installed has worked 
but Curl is not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"hello";
}
```

this gives me the error

```
1. #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/mnt/d/projectsc++/scrap/main.cpp).
2. cannot open source file "curl/curl.h"
3. curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
```

But as i try to run

```
./vcpkg install curl
```

it shows me that curl is already installed and configured .

```
 Computing installation plan...
 The following packages are already installed:
 curl[core,non-http,openssl,ssl]:x64-linux
 Package curl:x64-linux is already installed

 Total elapsed time: 36.7 us

 The package curl:x64-linux provides CMake targets:

find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

I am pretty new to this so i dont understand w hole lot of it but can someone explain what error am i doing...

Answer (score 1):

find_package should usually find the include dir. But see if by adding the following works after find_package command of yours.

**include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})**